# Testing the formatting for different locales

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-adf

How to set the Number columns to format the data based on the region of the client. Suppose if the request comes from USA user the number should be shown like - **1,000,000.99** and if the request comes from France, the number should be shown as - **1 000 000,00**.

I am trying to achieve this functionality in the JDeveloper ADF 11g application. I have used  on the number columns and set the locale to 
"#{requestContext.formattingLocale}". 
Now I want to test this.

Is there a way to make the application pick up the locale from my computer's region settings. I have tried setting my laptop's region to France, but it seems like the JDeveloper is not picking it up. I am still seeing the format as USA number format

Answer (score 0):

In the view tag change the locale attribute to test different locales